# Grunt task containing multiple spawn tasks will only run the first task

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, spawn

I have the following three tasks set up which use `grunt.util.spawn` to handle various Git tasks:

```
grunt.registerTask('git-add', function() {
  grunt.util.spawn({
    cmd : 'git',
    args: ['add', '.'],
  });
});

grunt.registerTask('git-commit', function(message) {
  grunt.util.spawn({
    cmd : 'git',
    args: ['commit', '-m', message],
  });
});

grunt.registerTask('git-push', function(origin, branch) {
  grunt.util.spawn({
    cmd : 'git',
    args: ['push', origin, branch],
  });
});
```

Running each of these individually works as aspected, so by running:

```
$ grunt git-add
$ grunt git-commit:"commit message"
$ grunt git-push:origin:"branch name"
```

I can successfully commit and push my changes. So how come when combining these 3 tasks into their own task like so, only the first task (git-add) gets run?

```
var target = grunt.option('target');

grunt.registerTask('push-feature', [
  'git-add',
  'git-commit:' + target,
  'git-push:origin:feature/' + target
]);
```

I should be able to run `$ grunt push-feature --target=12345`, assuming my branch is called 12345, to have all those 3 tasks run, but only the first git-add task runs. If I remove the git-add task, the next one (git-commit) is the only task which executes.

What am I missing to just be able to have these 3 tasks run in sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be due to async trouble.

Try to mark your tasks as async when declaring them, and use the callback option for spawn. Here's an example with your first task:

```
grunt.registerTask('git-add', function () {

    var done = this.async(); // Set the task as async.

    grunt.util.spawn({
        cmd: 'git',
        args: ['add', '.']   // See comment below about this line
    }, done);                // Add done as the second argument here.
});
```

Also note you have an additional comma, that may be interfering with operation:

```
args: ['add', '.'], // <- this comma should be dropped.
```

Comment: Amazing, and perfect! Thank you very much, just was I was looking for.

Comment: Glad I was able to help! :)